# Error message "You must set the product id if you set the unit id" in workflow

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, workflow, product

I have built a workflow that when qualifying opportunities, adds the opportunity items to the order.

In QA and PROD the workflow works fine.

However, in DEV I get this error message:

Plugin Trace:[Microsoft.Crm.Workflow: Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.Activities.InvokeSdkMessageActivity]
[InvokeSdkMessageStep12: Get Products]    [Microsoft.Dynamics.Sales.Plugins: Microsoft.Dynamics.Sales.Plugins.MainOperationGetSalesOrderProductsFromOpportunity]
    [bdd5c76b-ed99-e611-80ee-00155dc13806: GetSalesOrderProductsFromOpportunity of salesorder]
    Entered Microsoft.Dynamics.Sales.Plugins.MainOperationGetSalesOrderProductsFromOpportunity.Execute(), Correlation Id: fd6349a4-baa0-4161-b56e-d5838290e8e1, Initiating User: a17d01bd-d06f-e811-a971-000d3a2acc1e
    Exiting Microsoft.Dynamics.Sales.Plugins.MainOperationGetSalesOrderProductsFromOpportunity.Execute(), Correlation Id: fd6349a4-baa0-4161-b56e-d5838290e8e1, Initiating User: a17d01bd-d06f-e811-a971-000d3a2acc1e
    
        [Microsoft.Dynamics.Sales.Plugins: Microsoft.Dynamics.Sales.Plugins.PreOperationSalesOrderLineCreate]
        [ef56ab95-e28e-e611-80f1-00155dc13602: Microsoft.Dynamics.Sales.Plugins.PreOperationSalesOrderLineCreate: Create of salesorderdetail]
        Entered Microsoft.Dynamics.Sales.Plugins.PreOperationSalesOrderLineCreate.Execute(), Correlation Id: fd6349a4-baa0-4161-b56e-d5838290e8e1, Initiating User: a17d01bd-d06f-e811-a971-000d3a2acc1e
        Exception: Microsoft.Dynamics.Solution.Common.CrmException: You must set the product id if you set the unit id. (Fault Detail is equal to Exception details: 
        ErrorCode: 0x80043B11
        Message: You must set the product id if you set the unit id.
        StackTrace: 
           at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
           at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
           at Microsoft.Dynamics.Solution.Common.CrmException.BuildOrganizationServiceFault(Exception innerException, Int32 errorCode, Int32 statusCode, String message)
           at Microsoft.Dynamics.Solution.Common.CrmException..ctor(String message, Exception innerException, Int32 errorCode, Int32 statusCode, Boolean isFlowControlException, Boolean enableTrace)
           at Microsoft.Dynamics.Solution.Common.CrmException..ctor(String message, Exception innerException, Int32 errorCode, Int32 statusCode, Boolean isFlowControlException)
           at Microsoft.Dynamics.Solution.Common.CrmException..ctor(String message, Int32 errorCode)
           at Microsoft.Crm.Sales.ObjectModel.QOIDetailService.Validate(Entity qoiDetail, Entity parentQoi, Boolean IsCreate, IPluginContext context)
           at Microsoft.Crm.Sal...)., Correlation Id: fd6349a4-baa0-4161-b56e-d5838290e8e1, Initiating User: a17d01bd-d06f-e811-a971-000d3a2acc1e
        Exiting Microsoft.Dynamics.Sales.Plugins.PreOperationSalesOrderLineCreate.Execute(), Correlation Id: fd6349a4-baa0-4161-b56e-d5838290e8e1, Initiating User: a17d01bd-d06f-e811-a971-000d3a2acc1e
Error Message:Exception type: Microsoft.Dynamics.Solution.Common.CrmException
Message: You must set the product id if you set the unit id.
   at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.Services.InvokeSdkMessageService.Execute(ActivityContext executionContext, Activity activity, CompletionCallback callBack)
   at System.Activities.NativeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
-- End stack trace --

If you have any idea what could be the problem, I am very much looking forward to your feedback.

Kind Regards

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A) Anytime you're asking for help with a custom code exception, you should post the code.
B) Since this works in some environments it might be a data problem. Maybe the product ids are set in QA and DEV but not in PROD.